# The error of mapping two classes with auto mapper

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have two classes at the project level, I want to map them with Auto Mapper, but there is a mapping error, can you help me?

```
public class RegisterVm
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class RegistrationRequest
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Received error

[image: Error Image]

I used the following code to map, but I got an error

```
CreateMap<RegisterVm, RegistrationRequest>().ReverseMap();
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

Remove ReverseMap() and write the code similar to:

CreateMap<RegisterVm, RegistrationRequest>();